# from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext ImportError: No module named streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
ImportError: No module named streaming

this error is coming when I try to use streaming through pyspark. I am succesfully able to use streaming through scala.

import org.apache.spark.streaming._

does not give error and i am able to run the program.

I am running spark on http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-apache-spark-hdp/

Answer (score 0):

The Python API for Spark Streaming is recent, it was added in the 1.2 release (read [changelog](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-1-2-0.html)). Check which version you are using?